# Java selenium select

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

i'm trying for the past two hours to klick on "Herr". Would be great if you can help me guys.

Html

```
<div class="dropdown_box dropdown_box_anrede mandatory">
            <div style="display: block;" class="replace" id="anrede_select_replace">
                <div class="current" id="anrede_select_current">
                    <div class="text">Anrede</div>
                </div>
                <ul class="options" id="anrede_select_options" style="display:none;">
                    <li id="anrede_select_Herr"><div class="text">Herr</div></li><li id="anrede_select_Frau"><div class="text">Frau</div></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

code right now

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='anrede_select_current']/div']/div")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='anrede_select_Herr']/div")).click();
```

Thanks

Comment: ul tag display is set to none, it is not visible, so all the enclosed li tags are also not visible. If it is not visible webdriver wont find it.

Comment: Thanks, have to wait a second until it is visible.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to `click` on `<div>` with id `anrede_select_replace` first then try using `WebDriverWait` to wait until option with id `anrede_select_Herr` getting visible as below :-

```
driver.findElement(By.id("anrede_select_replace")).click();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement herr = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("anrede_select_Herr"));
herr.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make it visible first by opening the dropdown

```
driver.findElement(By.className("dropdown_box_anrede")).click();
// or
driver.findElement(By.id("anrede_select_replace")).click();
```

And then you can click on the option